# Существует ли встроенные или системные функции для позиционирования консоли, в windows, на С++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как вариант, можно ли скрыть как-то консоль?

Comment: У вас приложение оконное или консольное? Делаете оконное — и нет никакой консоли. Или вам надо, чтоб она то была, то пропадала? Вобщем, изъяснитесь подробнее, pls...

Comment: Ну, скажем, я использовал библиотеку "SFML", консоль никуда не пропала. Ну окей, один из вариантов решений я примерно понимаю, но вопрос был в другом, а именно как управлять консолью, если она в программе в наличии?

Comment: Консоль не является частью программы, поэтому и управлять ей нельзя. Взаимодействие сводится к чтению/записи через стандартные потоки ввода.

Comment: Так все-таки что вам нужно, скрыть консоль или двигать ее? Решения будут совсем разные. Скрывается она специальным флагом компилятора (`-mwindows` для GCC, в студии что-то свое).

Comment: Убрать ее вовсе можно, указав, что приложение оконное (даже если оно не является таковым): `editbin /subsystem:windows filename.exe`. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы просто неверно создаете оконное приложение...

Comment: `FreeConsole` почитайте

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ. Однако осталась последняя часть вопроса, а каким образом можно управлять например положением консоли?

Comment: Положением? Получить handle, а затем - SetWindowPos